# Linux rsync archive flag over nfs mount anomaly

Tags: archive, rsync

I need to rsync a small directory from an NFS in the US to an NFS in India at least one time per day via a mounted directory at the source end. I want to retain all attributes so I'm using the archive flag, but owner is changed to me at the receiving end. I am running the job as my user ID not root, but that should not matter should it?

Regards
-John

Comment: do you have access to the remote machine ?? like can you ssh to it ?and do you have privileges to access the mount point?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does matter. See here

https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share

The user id you've mounted the remote host on may be different than the one you're logged in as on the local host.